# Visual Studio 2010 Project error on the Target machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I was working in an C# project in Visual Studio 2010 but after creating of the Setup installer I can install in my own machine and all works OK, but when I install in other target machine and when in run it gives the following error:

> Event : CLR20r3
>
> System.Io.FileNotFoundException

Any suggestions to overcome this problem. I have the same version o .Net on target machine.
I think is using something of Visual Studio because I uninstall visual studio in my machine the error raises. All dependencies are set to copy local = true.
AI think something on the Visual Studio Installer creation is not being ported to the final project.

Any Suggestion are welcome.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add the error it's giving?

Comment: Please find on the dropbox Links: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9y2in6x6avq4g20/ErrorMac.png https://www.dropbox.com/s/sou4svit9bk0w30/error1.png

Comment: Did you look at this page: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/63a3dd20-6ac0-4d7b-8f7b-7b99c81956f9/clr20r3?forum=winformssetup ?

Comment: Thanks For the Link. Problem Solved. Just some permission when building the msi setup.